# Objective-C, Could someone show me how to copy array of objects to array of dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of objects named MyArray, it holds objects MyItem. Here is MyItem class

```
@interface MyItem : NSObject
@property NSString *text;
@property BOOL completed; 
@end
```

I have verified content of MyArray all data looks good. Now that I want to loop thru MyArray copy its elements to another array of dictionary so that I can write to my existing property list. I thought I could do something like below, but it didn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [MyArray count]; i++) {
    MyItem *item = [MyArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *newDictionary =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"text",item.text,
                                  @"completed", [NSNumber numberWithBool:item.completed] ,nil];

    [tempArray addObject: newDictionary];
}
```

The result of the new array looks strange:

```
Text= (null), Completed= (null)
Text= (null), Completed= (null)
Text= (null), Completed= (null)
Text= (null), Completed= (null)
```

Could someone shed some light what I did wrong there. thanks in advance!

Comment: where do you create tempArray? how do you log it? You should use faset enumeration instead of calling `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: Why do you want to turn this object into a dictionary?  There are three better options.  1. Just use the object as is.  2. Don't use the object in the first place, but start with a dictionary instead.  3. Give the `MyItem` class a method that returns a dictionary representation of the object. -- Iterating through the entire array to create a dictionary representation of all the objects in it is a waste given these 3 alternatives.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am totally new with Objective-C, currently I am in the "get it to work" mode, so I didn't think that far. Thanks for pointing that out and your example works great. Thanks again. could you explain this what are we doing here: @(item.completed) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fast enumeration and modern syntax:

```
tempArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (MyItem *item in myArray){
    NSDictionary *newDictionary = @{@"text": item.text, @"completed": @(item.completed) };
    [tempArray addObject: newDictionary];
}
```

Comment: Actually, make the body of the loop just `[tempArray addObject:[item dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:@[@"text", @"completed"]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [MyArray count]; i++) {
MyItem *item = [MyArray objectAtIndex:i];

// I think you have a mistake here
// dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys : object first, then key. But your code: key first, then key
NSDictionary *newDictionary =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              item.text,@"text",
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:item.completed],@"completed",nil];

[tempArray addObject: newDictionary];
}
```

Comment: I read your example back and forth and down to top but still couldn't see the difference in your code and mine. did you miss something?

Comment: I mean [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"object", @"key"]. But in your code, you place [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"key, @"object"] (the opposite == not right). I have comment in your code.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you, I wondering why it is called Object and Key, It looks more like value and key to me?